# Multiprocessing in python. Can a multiprocessed function call functions as multiprocesses?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Recently I have started using the multiprocessor pool executor in python to accelerate my processing.

So instead of doing a

```
list_of_res=[]
for n in range(a_number):
    res=calculate_something(list_of sources[n])
    list_of_res.append(res)
joint_results=pd.concat(list_of_res)
```

I do

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    joint_results=pd.concat(executor.map(calculate_something,list_of_sources))
```

It works great.

However I've noticed that inside the `calculate_something` function I call the same function like 8 times, one after another, so I might as well apply a map to them instead of a loop

My question is, can I apply multiprocessing to a function that is already being called in multiprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can have a worker process spawn another pool of workers, but it is not optimal.

each time you launch a new process it takes a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds for this new process to initialize and start executing work (OS, disk and code dependent.)

launching a worker from a worker is just wasting the overhead of spawning the first child to begin with, and you are better off extracting the loop inside `calculate_something` and launching it directly within your initial executor.

a better approach is to launch your initial `calculate_something` using a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) and have one shared `ProcessPoolExecutor` that all your thread workers will push work into, this way you can limit the number of newly created processes and avoid creating and deleting much more workers than you actually need, and it takes only a few microseconds to launch a threadpool.

this is an example of how to nest threadpool and process_pool.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

def process_worker(n):
    print(n)
    return n

def thread_worker(list_of_n,process_pool:ProcessPoolExecutor):
    work_done = list(process_pool.map(process_worker,list_of_n))
    return work_done

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_lists_of_n = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as process_pool, ThreadPoolExecutor() as threadpool:
        tasks = []
        work_done = []
        for item in list_of_lists_of_n:
            tasks.append(threadpool.submit(thread_worker,item,process_pool))
        for item in tasks:
            work_done.append(item.result())
    print(work_done)
```

Comment: Interesting. I kind of understand the first approach. About the second approach do you have something like a draft simple example of this combination of ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor?

Comment: I run the example and for some reason the first time it run the program twice....(after that, only one time the expected output)

Comment: I tried it and is working fine. One question: In the line where `task.append` , does it guarantee me that the results of the processing is going to be in the right order (in `work_done`)?  (so far in my experiments they are, I just want to know if there is a guarantee of this)

Comment: @KansaiRobot the above code with `task.append` and `work_done.append` guarantees the results are in the same order that they were submitted, it doesn't do any guarantee on the order of which they are executed, the OS might choose to execute the second one then the first one then the fifth one then the third one etc ... only the results will be in the order at which they are submitted.

Comment: Ah yes of course. the execution I saw is not ordered as expected. The results are though.

Comment: One quick question, if I don't put the `max_workers=8` in ProcessPoolExecutor, , does the machine runs to its maximum capacity or should I specify it?

Comment: @KansaiRobot leave it blank unless you want to limit it or you are IO bound and want to increase it `If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine. If max_workers is less than or equal to 0, then a ValueError will be raised. On Windows, max_workers must be less than or equal to 61. If it is not then ValueError will be raised. If max_workers is None, then the default chosen will be at most 61, even if more processors are available.` https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor